# How to pass variable to screen flow from lightning aura component for creating new records

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-flow-builder

There is a particular object `Playbook__c` which has master detail relationship with Contact. In this `Playbook__c` object, there is `Contact__c` field which is basically the master detail field.

Now our requirement is: whenever anyone press the "new" button to create it should redirect to the Screen flow. For that we are using Aura component to override the standard button and redirect it to screen flow. In that screen flow we created this variable `recordId` which is basically equals to the `contact__c`. Now `contact__c` is a lookup field,so that we can have the ability to pick any contact.
This flow is working fine. We want this `recordId` to be dynamic. But, now we are unable to pass it.
The aura component code is below:

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="Boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.Init}"/>   
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" class="slds-modal__close" onclick="{!c.closeFlowModal}"/>
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowOutput" onstatuschange="{!c.closeModalOnFinish}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

The JS code is below:

```js
({
Init : function(component, event, helper) {
       
component.set("v.isOpen", true);    
       
var flow = component.find("flowOutput");
// Added the below piece of code to pass the input parameters
    
var inputVariables = [ 
            {
                name : "recordId",
                type : "String", 
                value : component.get("v.recordId")
            }
        ];
       flow.startFlow("LFS_Playbook_Creation_Page_Screen_Flow",inputVariables);
    },

closeFlowModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    },

closeModalOnFinish : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
            component.set("v.isOpen", false);
        }
    }
})
```

Now when I am pressing the new button then I am getting error as recordId is null and the variable type is string, Please kindly help.

Comment: screen flow is coming fine,but just that recordId issue.I am getting this below error:

Comment: We can't launch this flow because of a variable error. Send this error message to your admin. The value null is being provided for variable recordId but isn't compatible with the variable's data type (String). Check the places where you implemented the flow ‒ such as through a Lightning page or a custom button ‒ and make sure that all provided values are compatible with the variables' data types.